# Is there a way to refresh/reload just a component inside a page (But not the page where the component is called)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm new to Angular + Ionic. Is there a way I can reload/refresh a component inside a page.? It seems that it is the way I can solve my problem right now. I tried the  `location.reload()` and it does reload/refresh the component but it also reloads the whole page which I do not want.

The component is an image picker/ camera and the page is a form.

thePage

```
<ion-content> 
    <form>
      ..
      ..
      ..
      .. 
      <the-component>
          ....
      </the-component>

    </form>

<ion-content>
```

Comment: What is the reason to reload the whole component? The only way to do that is to unmount the component from the DOM and then remount it. That can essentially be done by using an `*ngIf` in the parent Component and rendering the `the-component` accordingly.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to "reload/refresh" the component, i.e. take it off DOM and put it back on. Rather, you can reload/repopulate the data which will essentially reload the component with new data. Because of data binding, Angular detects the changes and will show the new data in the template (html).

Comment: @SiddAjmera @Riv  ``` *ngIf` ``` did fix my problem. I was using it prior to this question but in a wrong way so I thought it does not work.